# Page doesn't load correctly with Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, loading, mozilla

I have some problem with my website on Mozilla's firefox loading. The fact is, that my slider's images are put one behind the other, before the sliders puts himself in place correctly after the page is 100% loaded.

It's really sad :(

The horrible thing is here : (it works fine with Google Chrome) http://dooweet.org/main

Do you have some solution to make my page displayed when it is completely loaded with mozilla ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Not sure what you are seeing but they look the same in firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Assign `.main-container` (or maybe `.container1` or `#home_featured`) a height and hide the overflow

```
.main-container { height:302px; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: It helped me a bit, but the problem is half solved :p. The loading is now better, but the page loading is not as good as it should be. When you look at it, some elements are not in their place when it loads. Some other idea ? :)

Comment: I dont see anything out of place anymore. Can you be more specific?

Comment: It's ok, i used a new method :P

<body onload="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display = 'block';" style="display:none;">

Is it ok ?